# What is the minimum version of bash (including minor version) that supports case substitution?

Tags: bash

By that, I mean the built-in bash string operators `${lowercase^^}` and `${uppercase,,}`.  I just wondered what the minimum version is that supports it.  Googling indicates version 4.x.  But what is version .x?  Version 4.3.1 or 4.0?

There doesn't seem to be a change log on http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/

Comment: For future questions of this form, http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges is a good resource if the NEWS file doesn't provide an answer (which it generally will).

Comment: (I'm a bit split on how to handle this question -- building a knowledge base full of questions that could be answered by consulting changelogs or similar easily located offsite resources isn't a great use of folks' time, but on the other hand, the currently proposed move-to-superuser close reason doesn't seem a great fit -- this _is_ relevant to programming, just as much as a similar question about any other programming language's changes over time would be).

Comment: I did in fact Google this for quite some time before posting.  I couldn't find what I was looking for.  Within a minute of posting here, I got an answer and one I was looking for.  I appreciate that questions like this are distasteful to some people, but nevertheless, it was both useful and satisfied my query - take from that what you will.

Comment: The very first Google result for "bash features by version" answers your question. Picking good search strings is important.

Comment: Very well done, you are a master of Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's added in 4.0. See the [NEWS](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS) file in Bash source code:

```
This is a terse description of the new features added to bash-4.0 since
the release of bash-3.2.  As always, the manual page (doc/bash.1) is
the place to look for complete descriptions

... ...

hh. There are new case-modifying word expansions: uppercase (^[^]) and
    lowercase (,[,]).  They can work on either the first character or
    array element, or globally.  They accept an optional shell pattern
    that determines which characters to modify.  There is an optionally-
    configured feature to include capitalization operators.
```

Comment: The `NEWS` is what I was looking for.  Just a note: I am running `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` and searching for that description in `man 1 bash` returns `Pattern not found  (press RETURN)`.  The man page was in fact the first place I looked and I use the man page very frequently.

Comment: Sure, I found the documentation for `,,` and `^^`.  But my question surrounded what precise version this was introduced - not in the man page (unfortunately).  Ironically, there is a `COPYING` file under `/usr/share/doc/bash-4.1.2` but no `CHANGELOG`, which is a shame.